# How to get variable from href using php

Tags: php

This code for getting order_no when click on link, I can't implement any javascript on this page because its work like template and its not the page appear in browser, any way its working fine but if i click on the link and open modal it shows the same order_no, I have to refresh page or open in new tab to get order_no.
sorry for my english, wish you got what i mean

```
   <td align='center'  span style="font-weight:bold;"><a href ="edit.php?id=<?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?>" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#action"><?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?></a></td>
```

**edit.php**

```
 <?php
require_once 'config.php';
$q_edit_student = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_no` = '$_REQUEST[id]'") or die(mysqli_error());
$f_edit_student = $q_edit_student->fetch_array();
?>


<div class = "modal-content ">
<div class  = "modal-body">

 <div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Order Number</label>
    <input type = "text" name = "order_no"  id="order_no" value = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['id']?>"tabindex="1" class="form-control" autofocus />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Im glad it wasn't just me..

Comment: what's an herf?

Comment: this looks soOOOooo much like your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41954044/how-to-store-id-from-link-into-database-without-going-to-another-page-using-php

Comment: Do you mean how to trigger PHP by using `$_GET` ?

Comment: and where's `$f_customer` that coming from? You sure put a LOT of guesswork in all your questions

Comment: the first code for sending order_no to edit.php , edit.php open in modal(popup screen) but what ever the order_no was in the table, it shows in edit.php page the first order_no which I clicked for first time.
but if i click order_no on new tab, its working fine

Comment: Looks like your combining your client and server side scripts.  You have to send the request to the server.  When you get a response on the client side you update the screen.  Where is that happening for you?

Comment: Given we are guessing, here's my guesswork answer.. you need to run `if (isset($_GET['id']))` and then execute your code within that.

Comment: may you didn't get what i mean

Answer (score 0):

From what little i am understanding from the question. I am guessing that you are trying to show an edit form for a particular order

Try the following

HTML

```
<a class="edit_link" href ="edit.php?id=<?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?>" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#action"><?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?></a>
```

Javascript

```
$(".edit_link").click(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.get(href).done(function(data){
        $("#action>.modal-body").html(data);
    });
});
```

some thing like this will do it for you.

Comment: I can't implement javascript, in check_data.php here my full code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41923308/how-to-update-specific-record-in-table-using-php-mysqli