# How to pass a value by href to a php page to retrieve the rest of the data from a row of table

Tags: php

I want to pass value by href, my problem is what ever i do click on id(order_no) on a table, a modal shows the same value.
Please check the image attached and help me:
[why i get the same value in popup modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndz8v.png)

```
   <td align='center'  span style="font-weight:bold;"><a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?>" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#action"><?php echo $f_customer['order_no']?></a></td>
```

**Edit.php**

```
  <?php $id = $_GET['id']; ?>

<div class="form-group col-xs-4 col-md-4">
<label for="name" class="control-label">Order Number</label>
<input type = "text" name = "order_no"  id="order_no" value = "<?php echo $id ?>"tabindex="1" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: This is a bootstrap/javascript issue.   If you use an inspector and look at the http requests being made, I suspect you will find that there is no request going to edit.php.  The Modal dialog is on the page with your list of orders.

Comment: Are you creating your `a` in a loop?

Comment: This is very similiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961579/how-to-get-variable-from-href-using-php

Comment: so any help please?